# How to replace exec command with system command in php

Tags: php, system, exec

Here is my Code to Generate PHP certification

To Generate CSR

```
 if(isset($_POST['gencsr']))
    {   
            AddLog("sslconfig.php","gencsr",ERR_ERROR);

            /* Storing the values entered by the user for re-display in case a validation check fails */
            $_SESSION['dummycountryname']   = trim($_POST["countryname"]);
            $_SESSION['dummyprovince'] = trim($_POST["province"]);
            $_SESSION['dummylocalityname'] = trim($_POST["localityname"]);
            $_SESSION['dummyorganizationname']     = trim($_POST["organizationname"]);
            $_SESSION['dummyorganizationunit']    = trim($_POST["organizationunit"]);
            $_SESSION['dummycommonname']       = trim($_POST["commonname"]);
            $_SESSION['dummyemail']       = trim($_POST["email"]);

        if($_POST['countryname']=='')
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummycountryname']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter country name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }
        if(strlen($_POST['countryname'])!=2)
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummycountryname']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter country name in two letters.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }
        if(!eregi("^[a-zA-Z]+$",$_POST['countryname'])) 
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummycountryname']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter valid country name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }

        if($_POST['province']=='')
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummyprovince']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter province name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }

        if(!eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9 \.-]+)*[a-zA-Z0-9\.]$",trim($_POST['province']))) 
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummyprovince']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter valid province name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }
        if($_POST['localityname']=='')
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummylocalityname']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter locality name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }
        if(!eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9 \.-]+)*[a-zA-Z0-9\.]$",trim($_POST['localityname']))) 
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummylocalityname']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter valid locality name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }
        if($_POST['organizationname']=='')
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummyorganizationname']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter organization name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }
        if(!eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9 \.-]+)*[a-zA-Z0-9\.]$",trim($_POST['organizationname']))) 
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummyorganizationname']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter valid organization name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }
        if($_POST['organizationunit']=='')
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummyorganizationunit']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter organizational unit name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }
        if(!eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9 \.-]+)*[a-zA-Z0-9\.]$",trim($_POST['organizationunit']))) 
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummyorganizationunit']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter valid organizational unit name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }

        if($_POST['commonname']=='')
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummycommonname']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter common name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }

        $pos = strpos($_POST['commonname'],'.');
        if($pos===false)
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummycommonname']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter valid common name.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }

        $hostname = substr($_POST['commonname'],0,$pos);
        $domainname = strstr($_POST['commonname'], '.');
        $domainname = substr($domainname,1);
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$hostname,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$domainname,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
        if(!validateHostName($hostname)||$hostname=="")
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummycommonname']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter valid common name.');
            $error_text="Please enter valid common name.'";
            AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }
        if(!validateDomainName($domainname))
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummycommonname']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter valid common name.');
            $error_text="Please enter valid common name.'";
            AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }
        if(!validateEmail($_POST['email']))
        {
            unset ($_SESSION['dummyemail']);
            seterror('0:|:  :|: Please enter valid email address.');
            header("Location: ssl.php");
            exit;
        }

    $dn = array("C" => "".trim($_POST['countryname']),
       "ST" => "".trim($_POST['province']),
       "L" => "".trim($_POST['localityname']),
       "O" => "".trim($_POST['organizationname']),
       "OU" => "".trim($_POST['organizationunit']),
       "CN" => "".trim($_POST['commonname']),
       "emailAddress" => "".trim($_POST['email']));

        // Generate a new private (and public) key pair
        $privkey = openssl_pkey_new();
        AddLog("sslconfig.php","privkey:".$privkey,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);

        $csr = openssl_csr_new($dn,$privkey);   
        openssl_csr_export($csr, $csrout);

        sendmail($csrout);
        AddLog("sslconfig.php","csr:".$csr,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
        openssl_csr_export_to_file ($csr,"/portal/data/config/certificate/CSR.crt");
        openssl_pkey_export_to_file ($privkey,"/portal/data/config/certificate/pk.key");
        unsetSessionVariables();
        header("Location: ssl.php");
        exit;
    }
```

and for del

```
// To Delete CSR
if(isset($_POST['delcsr']))
{
    if(unlink("/portal/data/config/certificate/pk.key") && unlink("/portal/data/config/certificate/CSR.crt"))
        seterror('8:|:  :|: CSR deleted successfully.');
    else
        seterror('0:|:  :|: CSR deletion failed.');
    unsetSessionVariables();
    header("Location: ssl.php");
    exit;
}
```

Now I want

1. Replace exec command with system command in php
2. And my new path is:
   **Generating a cert request**
   openssl req -new -nodes -out /portal/data/config/certificate/vendor/requests/couffin-req.pem -keyout /portal/data/config/certificate/vendor/requests/couffin-req.key -subj "/C=IN/ST=MAHARASHTRA/L=MUMBAI/O=Couffin Inc/OU=Sales/CN=www.couffin.itpl" -config /portal/data/config/certificate/vendor/openssl.cnf
   **Signing a cert request**
   openssl ca -policy policy_anything -batch -out /portal/data/config/certificate/vendor/certs/couffin-cert.pem -config /portal/data/config/certificate/vendor/conf/openssl.cnf -infiles /portal/data/config/certificate/vendor/requests/couffin-req.pem

Here some of the function i m using exec there

for example

```
function isp7bcertificate($p7btmpfilename)
{
    $cmd = 'openssl pkcs7 -in '.$p7btmpfilename;
    exec($cmd,$array1,$error_code);
    if($error_code==0)      // p7b certificate is PEM encoded
    {
        $error_text="certificate is in PEM p7b format";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
        return true;
    }
    // // p7b certificate is DER encoded
    $cmd = 'openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in '.$p7btmpfilename;
    exec($cmd,$array1,$error_code);
    if($error_code==0)
    {
        $error_text="certificate is in DER p7b format";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
        return true;
    }
    $error_text="certificate is not in p7b format";
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    return false;               // certificate not in p7b format.
}
```

and here

```
function uploadcert($certfilename,$pkfilename)
{
    $folderpath = '/portal/data/config/certificate/';
    $tmpfolderpath = '/portal/data/config/certificate/tmp/';
    $error_text="upload cert called";
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    if(!file_exists($tmpfolderpath.$certfilename))
    {
        $error_text="Certificate file not found.";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
        return "0:|:  :|: Certificate file not found.";
    }
    else
    {
        $error_text="Certificate file present.";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    }
    if(!file_exists($tmpfolderpath.$pkfilename))
    {
        $error_text="Private key file not found.";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
        return "0:|:  :|: Private key file not found.";
    }
    else
    {
        $error_text="Privatekey file present.";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    }

    // To fix Bug 5468 Starts
    if(!isbase64certificate($tmpfolderpath.$certfilename))
    {
        $error_text="Output : Failed to upload certificate.";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_ERROR);
        return "0:|: :|: Failed to upload certificate.";
    }

    //Fix for Bug 5195
    //Check if a private key corresponds to a selected certificate.
    $cert_content = file_get_contents($tmpfolderpath.$certfilename);
    $priv_key_content = file_get_contents($tmpfolderpath.$pkfilename);
    $error_text="openssl_x509_check_private_key called";
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    $output = openssl_x509_check_private_key($cert_content,$priv_key_content);
    $error_text="Output:".$output;
    AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    if($output)
    {
        $error_text="Output : Private Key OK";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $error_text="Output : Private Key NOT OK";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_ERROR);
        return "0:|: :|: Private key does not correspond to selected certificate.";
    }

    //first rename the current localhost.crt and localhost.key as old. and then copy new files.
    if (!copy($folderpath.'localhost.crt', $tmpfolderpath.'oldlocalhost.crt')) 
    {
        $error_text="error in localhost.crt copy to oldlocalhost.crt";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_ERROR);
        return "0:|: :|: Certificate file corrupted.";
    }
    else
    {
        $error_text="localhost.crt copied to oldlocalhost.crt";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    }
    if (!copy($folderpath.'localhost.key', $tmpfolderpath.'oldlocalhost.key')) 
    {
        //if copy of private key is failed restore the old localhost.crt
        copy($tmpfolderpath.'oldlocalhost.crt', $folderpath.'localhost.crt');
        $error_text="error in localhost.key copy to oldlocalhost.key";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_ERROR);
        return "0:|: :|: Private key file corrupted.";
    }
    else
    {
        $error_text="localhost.key copied to oldlocalhost.key";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    }

    $outcert = copy($tmpfolderpath.$certfilename, $folderpath.'localhost.crt');
    $outpk = copy($tmpfolderpath.$pkfilename, $folderpath.'localhost.key');

    if((!$outcert) || (!$outpk))
    {
        copy($tmpfolderpath.'oldlocalhost.crt', $folderpath.'localhost.crt');
        copy($tmpfolderpath.'oldlocalhost.key', $folderpath.'localhost.key');
        $cmd = 'service httpd restart';
        exec($cmd,$array1,$error_code);
        $error_text="Certificate and Private key copy error";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_ERROR);
        return "0:|:  :|: Certificate and Private key copy error.";
    }
    $cmd = 'service httpd restart';
    exec($cmd,$array1,$error_code);
    if($error_code!=0)
    {
        //httpd fail to start. Restore to original files
        copy($tmpfolderpath.'oldlocalhost.crt', $folderpath.'localhost.crt');
        copy($tmpfolderpath.'oldlocalhost.key', $folderpath.'localhost.key');
        $cmd = 'service httpd restart';
        exec($cmd,$array1,$error_code);
        $error_text="httpd fail to restart with new files";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_ERROR);
        //seterror('0:|:  :|: Certificate and Private key mismatched.');
        return "0:|:  :|: Certificate and Private key mismatched.";     
    }
    else
    {
        copy($tmpfolderpath.'oldlocalhost.crt', $folderpath.'localhost.crt');
        copy($tmpfolderpath.'oldlocalhost.key', $folderpath.'localhost.key');
        $cmd = 'service httpd restart';
        exec($cmd,$array1,$error_code);
        $error_text="httpd restart successful with new files";
        AddLog("sslconfig.php",$error_text,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
        return "success";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be a very short answer, but i don't know what else should be said:

since there aren't any `exec`-commands in your code, theres nothing to replace. conclusion: it's already done.

for replacing `exec`/`system` in general, thats just a small change in code:

```
exec($command,$return,$error);
```

simply gets

```
$return = system($command,$error);
```

for more information, read the [documentation for exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and [for system()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

Comment: :) I m using exec here not in this code $output = exec($cmd,$array1,$error_code);

Comment: so why are you posting a big bunch of code but not the relevant parts?

Comment: :) Actually my coding page is so long 1630 lines so ...  can i put my whole code here?

Comment: no, you only should post the _relevant parts of code_. that parts we need at least to understand what you're doing. if you ask how to replace `exec` with `system` in your code, you should show up where you're using `exec`, how you build the parameters for that and how you're processing it's return-values or error-messages.

Comment: maybe "$array1=system($cmd,$error_code);" is all you have to do, maybe not - try it, read the documentation and ask a specific question giving as much information as possible if you get any problems you can't solve on your own. this question is too incomplete to tell if you'll have to do anything more.

Comment: :) Yup sure can u plz give my 2nd ans